# How to declare a git branch as merged without adopting the changes in it?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, idioms

Suppose we have two git branches, `a` and `b` (say they're both local to keep things simple). Branch `a` is mine to work with, branch `b` isn't; I can't touch it.

I want to "declare" or "mark" a merge of `b` into `a`, without actually making any changes to the code in branch `a`. I don't mind making an empty commit to signify the merge. The motivation is that redundant work has happened on branch `b` which is subsumed by the work done on `a` since they diverged.

Assuming this is a "legitimate" thing to do - what's the idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: If you're on branch `good` and you wish to record a merge to signify that branch name `bad` should no longer be used, but you'd like to keep its commits (whether or not you keep its name later) without having anything in any of those commits affect your *current* branch, you just need `git merge -s ours bad`. This is pretty straightforward, so everyone here assumed you wanted the reverse: ignore all commits on `good` while staying on `good`, so that the next commit on `good` matches the commit on `bad`.

Comment: Logically, *that* would be `git merge -s theirs bad`, but `git merge -s theirs` does not exist. So this ends up being a common question. Since `git merge -s ours` *does* exist, nobody expects you to be asking how to run `git merge -s ours`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be easily made like this:

```
git commit-tree -p a -p b -m "not pulling b changes" a^{tree}
```

With this, you are asking git to create a new revision object that has `a` and `b` as parents, that has `a`s tree as its tree (so no differences against `a`) that has the comment that I provided there (adjust at will). The object will be created and the id will be printed on the stdout. You can check it to make sure it is what you want:

```
git diff that-id a
git log that-id
gitk that-id
```

There should be no differences. Then you can move a if you liked it:

```
git branch -f a that-id
```

Comment: You wrote that you _think_ this should work. So, will it, or won't t it? :-)

Comment: givr it a try. The first command will create an object that won't be pointed by anything so it's not like you will be busting something. The second one will allow you to check that there is indeed no difference... you might even check its log to see if it's just like what you wanted,

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it now:

1. `git br a`
2. `git merge --no-commit b` (or `git pull --no-commit remote-name-here b` if `b` is remote)
3. Unadding everything
4. Editing the commit conflicts to only keep the `a` version
5. `git commit` and changing the comment to say that I'm marking-as-merged without adopting changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no idiomatic way to do it, because it is not a common use case. Assuming, that you just don't want to have unmerged branches, there are some workarounds, that might work for you, depending on your circumstances:

1. Delete the branch
2. Merge the branch and then revert the merge commit (it is then merged, but the changes are not present)
3. Revert all commits on the branch and then merge it.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Rephrased to clarify that the idea is not to do anything with `b`.